# getDefaultProps with React Component Class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

When i declared `getDefaultProps` function inside Class which is inherit from `React.Component` this give Error like Below

[image]

I setup condition in constructor for initialize `props` its `undefined`.

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"

class App extends React.Component{
    propTypes:{
        techstack : React.PropTypes.string
    }

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.props.techstack === undefined ? "Rails" : ''
        console.log(this.props);
    }

    render(){
        return (<div>
                 <h2>{this.props.techstack} Rocks</h2>
                </div>
               )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById("app"));
```

Thanks advance for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After React's 0.13 release the `props` are required to be immutable. This being the case, `getDefaultProps` no longer makes sense as a function and should be refactored out to a property on the constructor, so

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"

class App extends React.Component{
    propTypes:{
        techstack : React.PropTypes.string
    }

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.props.techstack === undefined ? "Rails" : ''
        console.log(this.props);
    }

    render(){
        return (<div>
                 <h2>{this.props.techstack} Rocks</h2>
                </div>
               )
    }
}
    App.defaultProps = {key: 'value'};

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById("app"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"

class App extends React.Component{
    propTypes:{
        techstack : React.PropTypes.string
    }

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.props.techstack === undefined ? "Rails" : ''
        console.log(this.props);
    }

    render(){
        return (<div>
                 <h2>{this.props.techstack} Rocks</h2>
                </div>
               )
    }
}

App.defaultProps = { prop: 'value' };

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById("app"));
```

Answer (score 1):

The hint was in the error message, you need to use the static key word:

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"

class App extends React.Component{

    static propTypes:{
        techstack : React.PropTypes.string
    }

    static defaultProps: {
        techstack: 'Rails'
    }

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        console.log(props);
    }

    render(){
        return (<div>
                 <h2>{this.props.techstack} Rocks</h2>
                </div>
               )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById("app"));
```

Comment: Where are you console logging it though, and how? You should be taking advantage of defaultProps, instead of manually checking for undefined everywhere